# Buefy Carousel Thumbnail Indicator show duplicated image (Vuejs)

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, buefy

I'm trying to create a carousel with vertical thumbnails, but the thumbnails are being duplicated. I only have 2 image URLs, but it's showing 4 thumbnails.

*App.vue:*

```html
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <b-carousel
      :indicator-inside="false"
      class="is-hidden-mobile"
      :pause-hover="false"
      :pause-info="false"
    >
      <b-carousel-item v-for="(item, i) in imagess" :key="i">
        <figure class="image">
          <img :src="item.url">
        </figure>
      </b-carousel-item>
      <span v-if="gallery" @click="switchGallery(false)" class="modal-close is-large"/>
      <template slot="indicators" slot-scope="props">
        <span class="al image">
          <img v-for="(p,index) in imagess" :key="index" :src="p.url" :title="props.i">
        </span>
      </template>
    </b-carousel>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {},
  data() {
    return {
      bundledatas: null,
      imagess: [
        {
          url:
            "https://specials-images.forbesimg.com/imageserve/37645633/960x0.jpg?cropX1=445&cropX2=3910&cropY1=258&cropY2=2207"
        },
        {
          url:
            "https://www.sovereigngroup.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/HK-4.jpg"
        }
      ]
    };
  }
};
</script>

<style>
#app {
  font-family: "Avenir", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2c3e50;
  margin-top: 60px;
}
.is-active .al img {
  filter: grayscale(0%);
}
.al img {
  filter: grayscale(100%);
  margin: 2px 0;
}

.carousel {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto 25%;
  align-items: center;
}

.carousel-indicator {
  flex-direction: column;
}

.indicator-item {
  margin-right: initial !important;
}
</style>
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/focused-chatelet-qzh4b)

I only want to display 2 thumbnails for (one for each image) like this:

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your `indicators` slot is displaying *all* items of `imagess` when it should only be displaying the one specified in `props.i`, which is the current index shown in the carousel.

The solution is to lookup the item in `imagess` by the index in `props.i`, and set the `img`'s source URL accordingly:

```html
<template slot="indicators" slot-scope="props">
  <span class="al image">
    <!-- BEFORE: -->
    <!-- <img v-for="(p,index) in imagess" :key="index" :src="p.url" :title="props.i"> -->

    <img :src="imagess[props.i].url">
  </span>
</template>
```

[updated codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/youthful-violet-e2s6n?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&module=%2Fsrc%2FApp.vue&theme=dark)